# Access GADT contstraint from evaluation level

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, gadt

I am trying to make use of some of GADT parameter from runtime, assuming that I have used `DataKinds` extension to allow promoting data to types. i.e. having

```
data Num = Zero | Succ Num
data Something (len :: Num) where
  Some :: Something len
```

I would like to have function

```
toNum :: Something len -> Num
```

That for any `Some :: Something n` will return `n`:

```
toNum (s :: Something n) = n
```

Which is invalid in Haskell. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell this is impossible, since types are erased at runtime. That is, when the program will run, there is no information in memory about the value of the index `let` in the type.

To overcome this issue, we need to force Haskell to keep in memory that value, at runtime. This is usually done using a *singleton* auxiliary type:

```
data Num = Zero | Succ Num

data SNum (n :: Num) where
   SZero :: SNum 'Zero
   SSucc :: SNum n -> SNum ('Succ n)

data Something (len :: Num) where
  Some :: SNum len -> Something len
```

Using this you can easily write

```
sToNum :: SNum n -> Num
sToNum SZero = Zero
sToNum (SSucc n) = Succ (sToNum n)
```

and then

```
toNum :: Something len -> Num
toNum (Some n) = sToNum n
```

If you look up "haskell singletons" you should find several examples. There's even a `singletons` library to partially automatize this.

If / when "dependent Haskell" will be released, we will have less cumbersome tools at our disposal. Currently, singletons work, but they are a hassle sometimes. Still, for the moment, we have to use them.